# Database design: where to place the total amount fields

Tags: database-design

I am designing an app that tracks orders.  Each order can have > 1 workItem, and each workItem can have a separate price.

I was storing the prices of the workItem in the workItem table, thinking that in the UI, or for reports, gathering the job cost (both billed to the customer and paid to the contractor) would be calculated with a query of existing data in the workItems table.

Does it make sense to leave it this way or store the total amount in the Order table?  If I go with the latter, isn't the data redundant?  Maybe there are performance considerations of such a move.  What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how your database is being used.

The ideal solution would be to keep the separate items in your work item rows. That way you avoid duplication of data. For example, when you add or update a work item you would otherwise have to update both the work item and the total.

With appropriate indexes a query like this is typically performant:

```
SELECT i.*, SUM(wi.amount) total
FROM invoice i
JOIN workitem wi ON i.invoice_id = wi.invoice_id
GROUP BY i.invoice_id
```

That being said, *if* you find a performance problem with this you might denormalize your data model and store a total as well. But only go down that route if you need to. In my opinion, it shouldn't be done preemptively.

Comment: the database wouldn't be normalised if you have the price in the Order table. You should only do this if it is needed for some specific reason, perhaps for performance reason. As stated, it depends how your database is used.

Comment: @Tim: Your database could still be normalised even if you stored the price, it would just be to a different level: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Yep, OK - all of these comments make perfect sense... I really appreciate it.

Comment: And If I decided to de-normalize this total value. Does a **stored procedure** that updates the total value whenever a change happens in the workitem table considered a good solution to make sure the 2 values are synced at the database level ? or I update it at the PHP/application layer ?

Answer (score 3):

If you follow normalisation rules, you'll omit calculated values, such as Totals and generate them on the fly.

However, there sometimes occasions when you might choose to de-normalise a little and store such values explicitly.

In terms of storage space, it's generally not an issue on most platforms these days, so storing the extra data is not a problem. And sometimes you can improve performance or simplify your code, when de-normalising in this way. Equally, you decision can also effect maintainability, or perhaps increase complexity.

In your example, if you store the total against the order, every time you amend an item you are hitting the workitem table and then you have to update the order table as well. There seems to be little benefit to this, so I wouldn't go this route... but as I said, there are occasions where you might sensibly choose to store data, rather than derive it on the fly.

Comment: Yep, OK - all of these comments make perfect sense... I really appreciate it.

Comment: And If I decided to de-normalize this total value. Does a **stored procedure** that updates the total value whenever a change happens in the `workitem` table is a good solution to make sure the 2 values are synced at the database level ? or I update it at the PHP/application layer ?

Comment: @Accountantم you should really post this as a separate question. My view? If you truly want to denormalise, you would most likely use  AFTER Triggers. However, an alternative often might be to use Computed Columns - unfortunately these don't work across different tables, so a potential workaround would be to create an (Indexed) View. So rather than store the totals in the Invoice table, you could create an Invoice View that had the base data plus your calculated totals.

Comment: @CJM thank you very much for your time sir, I really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, performance and usage are the key to the correct descision here.  And what is the correct descision now may not be in the future.

A requirement may be to list all orders just displaying the total value.  If you don't store that value, you'd have to aggregate the order items for each order just to get the totals.  If you stored this value alongside the order table then you wouldn't need to include order items in the table.

You could extend this thinking to the number of order items too.  That value could be calculated, but if it was needed in the overview, big peformance gains may be gained just be storing it alongside the orders table.

Comment: Yep, OK - all of these comments make perfect sense... I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I would not store the total in your database unless performance becomes an issue.

Rather calculate it on the fly, as needed for reports or for display.